# parameterizing python POST request containing JSON body

Tags: python, json

I'm creating a Phyton script to POST a request which contains JSON BODY, 
This is the JSON input I need to pass in the body of the request :

```
{
   "Name": "PServiceGroup125",
   "ServiceIDs": [1330,2387]
}
```

I'm able to do this(it works) :

```
   body = "{\"Name\": \"PServiceGroup125\",\"ServiceIDs\": [1330,2387]}"
   headers = [ NVPair('Content-Type', 'application/json'), NVPair('UAMToken', uamtok) ]
   response = self.httpPost(self.hostPort, self.URI, headers, body)
```

What I'm trying to achieve:  ( to make it more "OO")

To create a function(say createBody ) to create a python object and then convert this python object into  JSON and pass it in the request:

```
def createBody(self):
    self.serviceDataProvider.setName("PTestServiceGroup %s" % time.strftime("%d%m%H%M%S"))
    self.serviceDataProvider.setServiceIDs(self.serviceDataProvider.nextItem())
```

I have two questions here :

Here I set the "value" for the corresponding json name and service ID field, how should I set the name field(ServiceIDs)?  ( "ServiceIDs": [1330,2387] )

Assuming that the  "serviceDataProvider" object has been created successfully(with  Name and ServiceID values ) .

how should i convert this object(serviceDataProvider) back to JSON and pass it in the request ?

I'm looking at the 'json' module , but not very clear on how to use it for this scenario

Anyones help and suggestion is appreciated !

```
# serviceDataProvider is object of class ServiceDataProvider 

class ServiceDataProvider(URLDataProvider):
    name =""
    sid=''
    sIDs=[]
    def setName(self,name):
        self.name=name

    def getName(self):
        return self.name

    def setServiceIDs(self,sid):
        sIDs=[]
        sIDs.append(sid)

    def getServiceIDs(self):
        return self.sIDs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all a bit over-engineered, and not really very Pythonic: at a guess, your previous experience is in Java...

There's not really any need for a class here, and even less for those getter/setters. It would be better to build this up as a Python dictionary, which can then be converted directly into JSON.

```
body = {}
body['Name'] = "PTestServiceGroup %s" % time.strftime("%d%m%H%M%S")
body['ServiceIds'] = [service_id1, service_id2]  # wherever these come from

data = json.dumps(body)
```

Comment: @ Daniel Roseman - Thanks , you got it ,  I'm was trying to do it the java way. This looks lot simpler,  So I'm trying the understand the code snippet a little bit, the "body = {}" creates a List or string ? and the data should be passed in the POST request ?

Comment: No, `{}` is a dictionary (ie a HashMap) - and yes, `data` is the stringified JSON which you can pass in the POST body.

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at `json.dumps` (converting a python dictionary structure to a json string) and `json.loads` (the reverse of `dumps`)

https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

Answer (score 1):

Python is an adult-consenting language, you don't need setters/getters.

I would use a python dict or an OrderedDict if you want your json to be in the same order, since python dicts doesn't keep keys in the same order they were inserted.